# how to find out how much money the user gave for a subscription or in-app purchase in iOS receipt?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, payment, subscription

I could not find in the Apple documentation how can I find out how much the user paid for a subscription or purchase? In different countries, the subscription price is different and depends on several factors including VAT.

Comment: Ever find the answer to this?